# YAML / YML unwanted auto-formatting

Tags: formatting, filetype-yaml

#### YAML / YML unwanted auto-formatting

The last days I made some **configuration** improvements of my vim environment, e.g. I installed vim-polyglot and coc and removed duplicated plugins within my vim-plug plugin manager.

However some very annoying effect occurs which I don't know how to handle, or respectively which plug or setting is responsible for it.

When I start editing for instance the aptitude configuration file `config` all the keys get extracted as demonstrated below:

- **before**

  ```
  Aptitude::UI::Styles {
    MenuBorder {fg black; bg blue; set bold};
  ```
- **after** writing vim formats it this way

  ```
  aptitude::UI "";
  aptitude::UI::Styles "";
  aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder "";
  aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder::fg "black";
  aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder::bg "blue";
  aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder::set "bold";
  ```

This file is a `yaml` / `yml` format.

I appreciate every hint for solving this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the active autocommands with `:au` to see if you could find the culprit and work your way backwards to the responsible plugin (or other origin)?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Tried to watch the output of `:au`, but the list is so long.  Maybe I have to make a trial and error configuration on a virtual machine. I set up to many plugins at once.

Comment: It probably hooks in to the `BufWritePre` event; `:au BufWritePre` should narrow it down. Could also be `BufWriteCmd`. Either way: this is definitely some plugin you've added; maybe ALE or something similar? Remove half of your plugins: if that fixes it add half back, and trial-and-error until you've narrowed it down. You can then look at the plugin where you can probably configure this behaviour.

Comment: Try some of the tips in [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: I had less time to make any progress. What I found out that this is an apt config file and maybe it is treaten that way (vim recognize that this is the `aptitutde` config file. However the settings for yaml are very suspicious.